# What is the shorcut key to open emoji picker on vs code on windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emoji

As suggested in most of the answers `Ctrl + i` is not working for me. I can't find the answer on the Internet.

Comment: the usual `CMD+CTRL+SPACE` doesn't work on mac :(

Answer (score 49):

You can use `Windows + .`

As a reminder, you can right-click in any text input (as the URL bar of your browser) to display the "Emoji" action with its shortcut on the side!

Answer (score 42):

**for windows**

windows key + .

**OR**

windows key + ;

**for Mac**

CTRL + CMD + Space

Answer (score 19):

[image]

## To use Emoji's

***For Windows***

```
`Window Key + .`
```

Window key and Full-Stop(Period) at the same time.

***For Mac***

```
CTRL + CMD + Space
```

Press and hold all keys at same time.You can almost use it anywhere where there is a textare;

Answer (score 3):

So  for windows the right method to get emojis is:

```
(win + > )
```

Comment: Hey, This didn't work for me, maybe you have a plugin. During text entry, type Windows logo key + . (period). The emoji keyboard will appear. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-keyboard-tips-and-tricks-588e0b72-0fff-6d3f-aeee-6e5116097942

Comment: It does not work instead use
windows key + .

OR

windows key + ;

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on VSCode @ linux Ubuntu 22.04, using this shortcut `CTRL + WINDOW KEY + i`. Hope this help. Thanks.
[image: emoji picker]

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04